# How are the Sitecore.XA nuget library file versions mapped to release version?

Tags: sxa

The Sitecore.XA libraries are available on the Sitecore MyGet feed but I'm not clear on how the dll file version maps to the version posted on dev.sitecore.net.

As of today (20180710) these are the versions listed:

[image]

I believe 2.7.0.1346 maps to SXA 1.7.0 initial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the detailed explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From the feed I see the following:

### Feed Entries

These are the entries you may see in the NuGet feed.

#### 9.1.1

- 4.8.1 : SXA 1.8.1

#### 9.1

- 4.8.0 : SXA 1.8.0

#### 9.0

- 3.8.1 : SXA 1.8.1
- 3.8.0 : SXA 1.8.0
- 3.7.1 : SXA 1.7.1
- 3.7.0 : SXA 1.7.0

#### 8.2

- 2.7.1 : SXA 1.7.1
- 2.7.0 : SXA 1.7.0

### Retired feed values

- 3.7.0.643 : SXA 1.7.1 rev. 180604 for 9.0
- 3.7.0.547 : SXA 1.7.0 rev. 180410 for 9.0
- 2.7.0.1435 : SXA 1.7.1 rev. 180604 for 8.2
- 2.7.0.1346 : SXA 1.7.0 rev. 180410 for 8.2